# How to view all resources created by beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can I have a view/list of all resources created by Beanstalk?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to **AWS CloudFormation**, and find stack representing your EB environment. In the stack you will find `Resources` tab, which will list everything created for the environment.